# Java Split() function giving Null pointer Exception error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public class url {


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL imdb = new URL("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The%20incredible%20Hulk");

    URLConnection yc = imdb.openConnection();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    String[] strarr = inputLine.split(",");


    System.out.println("splits.size: " + strarr.length);

    in.close();
}
}
```

The Error is : 
    "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at imdb.url.main(url.java:25)"

Please explain to me to how I can remove it.  I have googled a lot on using split function and null pointer exception, but just can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The is caused by `null.split(..)` work from there ..

Comment: Actually, that URL points to a JSON document, so you might want to use a JSON parser instead of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your while loop exits, `inputLine` is null, therefore calling `inputLine.split()` will always produce a `NullPointerException`.  I believe what you want to do is put curly brackets around the `System.out.println()` calls and everything in between, so that they are all included in the loop iteration:

```
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
 {
    System.out.println(inputLine);

    String[] strarr = inputLine.split(",");

    System.out.println("splits.size: " + strarr.length);
}
```

Does this have the intended effect?

Comment: Yes, it worked. And thanks to the explanation, now I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If a null is ever returned from `in.readLine()` in:

```
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
```

then the loop will exit and `inputLine` will remain null.

Logically, `inputLine` will **always** be null when the loop ends, so the exception in *inevitable*!

Answer (score 3):

you are missing parentheses in your while loop. causing `inputLine` to be null when you try to `split()` it. try

```
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);

    String[] strarr = inputLine.split(",");

    System.out.println("splits.size: " + strarr.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When `String[] strarr = inputLine.split(",");` is reached, you have read the whole response – but `inputLine` is `null` at that point, so you can't split it.

How to fix this depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to split the whole document, try collecting all the data in one big string:

```
String inputLine;
String allData = "";

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    allData += inputLine+"\n";
}

String[] strarr = allData.split(",");
```

(This code is a bit inefficient, but it should work.)

However, your URL points to a JSON document, so you might want to use a JSON parser instead of doing this. It will be more reliable and probably also easier than trying to parse JSON manually. For information on JSON and JSON libraries for various languages, see http://json.org .

Comment: thanks I'm trying to provide a utility to some people where a JSP grabs imdb ratings etc based on a movies list. I used this online IMDB Api for this purpose. Now I'll read up on using a JSON parser

Answer (score 1):

This is because when `inputline` read last time in `While` loop nothing is read in `inputLine` . So after `while` loop when you trying to `spli`t the `inputline`it is giving `NullPointerExcpetion`.

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
System.out.println(inputLine);//InputLine is null here.
String[] strarr = inputLine.split(",");//throwing NPE
```

The workaround is to use StringBuilder as follows:

```
StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            sbuilder.append(inputLine);
String[] strarr = (sbuilder.toString()).split(",");
```

Comment: Welcome..:) . I am glad that you got to know new thing by this post.